# Cannot start Concurrency Visualizer in Visual Studio 2012. Got error "Unable to start the ETW collection"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, profiling, data-profiling

When I tried to profile a WPF application with Concurrency Visualzer (tried both launch and attach to process), I got the following error pop up - **"Unable to start the ETW collection"**

ETW clearly means "Event Tracing for Windows", but I don't understand why VS cannot start it during profiling session. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12):

In my case this was due to Process Explorer. It seems that it uses ETW at some point to provide stats if you bring up a process' properties. Closing Process Explorer resolved my issue and allowed me to run the Concurrency Visualizer.

Comment: You saved my day. I have procexp always running and replaced taskmgr with it. I recorded several traces without any issues, always with enabled procexp but suddenly CV started to act sassy about that. I have no idea why. I always monitored thread count on the profiled process with procexp, restarted several times, nope. CV started to dislike procexp.

Comment: Same here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else running into this without access to tracelog.exe (which does not appear to be included in WDK 10).

List all Data Collector Sets:

```
logman -ets
```

For me the perpetrator was `NT Kernel Logger` which was stopped by

```
logman stop "NT Kernel Logger" -ets
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the Concurrency Visualizer extension in VS2015.

I downloaded the [Concurrency Visualizer Command Line Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh543788.aspx) and invoked `CVCollectionCmd /Query` (from an elevated prompt) but it would always say the following :
`Collection cannot start because the required ETW sessions are already in use.`

I got this error even after a reboot.

**The solution**

I ran `tracelog -x` (from an elevated prompt) and I stopped every running ETW session. After that `CVCollectionCmd /Query` said `Not collecting, ready to start.` and I was able to start the analysis from Visual Studio.

I couldn't determine which process or service on my computer started those ETW sessions.

Comment: I isolated it to "NT Kernel Logger" session. I killed only that and I could now run again. I did not have this problem yesterday, but I did install KB3165756 for VS2015 Update 3, and I also see a Windows Update security patch installed since then. Might be one of those introducing this, or simply having rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem today and if anyone is experiencing similar with VS 2019, the solution for me was to reboot Windows 10.

I also made sure that anything that's launching on startup and is not required is disabled (go to `Task Manager -> Start-up` tab and disable everything that you think might be causing this problem). After a reboot, I launched VS 2019 and tried running analyzer again (I used `Start with Current Process` menu item) and it worked just fine

NOTE: I literally opened only VS 2019, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by running

```
CVCollectionCmd /Detach
```